# jmap -heap cause jvm crash

Tags: java, jvm

#### QA

when we execute jmap -heap pid , the target java process can't handle any http request.

#### env

```
[nobody@aliyun-APP-250-245 code]$ uname -a
Linux aliyun-APP-250-245 2.6.32-696.10.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 18:51:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[nobody@aliyun-APP-250-245 code]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
[nobody@aliyun-APP-250-245 code]$ /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_112//bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

```
top - 16:14:27 up 783 days,  7:05, 26 users,  load average: 0.33, 0.54, 0.54
Tasks: 100 total,   0 running, 0 sleeping,   100 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.6%us,  2.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 82.1%id,  1.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16467076k total, 16191196k used,   275880k free,    54544k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  1679284k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15953 nobody    20   0 2309m 431m  14m S  0.0  2.7   0:00.14 java
16036 nobody    20   0 2309m 431m  14m S  0.0  2.7   0:00.22 java
15908 nobody    20   0 2309m 431m  14m S  0.0  2.7   0:00.00 java
15909 nobody    20   0 2309m 431m  14m S  0.0  2.7   0:07.91 java
15910 nobody    20   0 2309m 431m  14m S  0.0  2.7   0:00.32 java
```

all of them is stopped.

execute `curl` will read timeout. all of http request will failure

but at `centos 7` will be ok.

Is there any related link?

please forgive me my bad english :(

Comment: Different linux kernel version, 6.9 failed, 7.x is ok, this is too strange.

Comment: jstack and jmap -histo is ok.

Comment: Yes, that is a bit weird.  But CentOS 6.9 will be EOL in 8 months ... so the solution is obvious.  Upgrade to CentOS 7 or something else.

Comment: emmmm， maybe we upgrade some patch that maybe cause this, upgrade to 7 is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had received some warning about ECS from aliyun once, so we upgraded some patch.

from that, we found some software that be influenced, like glibc, then we upgrade glibc and jmap worked